# Command line argument explanation and program error

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have read to many questions on stackoverflow related to this topic but still haven't got it. Please explain the proper use of commandline arguments. They are passed when the code begins to execute is that what we are focusing on? But whats the use. Please link to some informative question of this type where i can read and understand this topic completely. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int i;
for(i= 1; i<argv; i++) \\error argument count should be used instead argument vector
    printf("%s%s", argv[i], (i< argc-1) ? " " : "" );
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you wanted to use `i<argc` within the `for` loop (instead of `i<argv`). The `argc` variable is the number of argument received by your program, whereas the variable `argv` holds the arguments.

Comment: oops sorry i reading for six hours and by this time i am completely exhausted :( thanks a lot for the help @SleuthEye

Comment: I would highly recommend running your program with warnings next time, because this kind of mistake is very common. On `gcc`, its the `-Wall` option

Comment: Plenty of info about command line and why you would use it with easy Google search, for example: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv/

Comment: I see nothing printf should have printed the string....how can i do so if i were to print "any string" as argv[i] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line arguments are used to pass information to the program when it is run without requiring any extra interaction from the user/script launching it. This can include things like paths to the files the program is working on or flags to define it's configuration and behaviour.

By using these rather than functions such as scanf it makes it much easier for the user to automate its launching, and integrate it with other programs.

edit: The original question contained code with a bug where argv had accidentally been used in place of argc, I'll leave the answer to that part of the question here for posterity:

---

Your for loop line should look like this:

```
for(i= 1; i<argc; i++)
```

`argc` gives the number of arguments that have been passed to the program. In the code you posted you are trying to compare the counter with `argv` which is a pointer to the space in memory which holds the arguments. To the computer this looks like an integer so it 'works' but is definitely not what you want.

Comment: *defintely isn't - is that what you meant?

Comment: edited my question that was an error. Now please relpy with an edited answer. Thankyou @thip

Comment: @Andrew_CS oops yes, fixed! thanks for the spot!

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan I've updated my answer, does this help? Also I think it's worth leaving in your original code with argv as a) the question title makes more sense with it and b) it's an easy mistake to make, leaving it in may help people in the future